# Calculate active users per month in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Every month I need to calculate how many "ambassadors" we have in our program. I currently have a very manual process where I create each month and specify how to count the users for that period.

This example is for creating September:

Full code:

```
SELECT
2021 AS 'year',
"September" AS month,
'Q3' AS quarter,
engagement_program.ambassadors.actimo_client_id AS 'client_id',
engagement_program.ambassadors.id AS 'amb_id',
engagement_program.customers.name AS 'company', 
actimo_clients.name AS 'client',
engagement_program.ambassadors.retailer,
engagement_program.countries.name AS 'country'

FROM engagement_program.ambassadors
LEFT JOIN engagement_program.actimo_clients
ON engagement_program.actimo_clients.id = engagement_program.ambassadors.actimo_client_id
LEFT JOIN engagement_program.customers
ON engagement_program.customers.id = engagement_program.ambassadors.customer_id
LEFT JOIN engagement_program.countries
ON engagement_program.countries.id = engagement_program.ambassadors.country_id

WHERE ambassadors.created_at<'2021-10-01' AND (ambassadors.deleted_at > '2021-09-30' OR ambassadors.deleted_at IS NULL) AND '2021-08-31'<now()

GROUP BY 'year','month','quarter',
engagement_program.ambassadors.actimo_client_id,
engagement_program.customers.name,
engagement_program.ambassadors.retailer,
engagement_program.ambassadors.id

UNION ALL

*SAME QUERY AS ABOVE BUT FOR NEXT MONTH*

;
```

- Ambassadors created before the end of the month are included.
- Ambassadors deleted before the end of the month are included or if the ambassador hasn't been deleted at all.

My question is how this could be automatised so I don't have to create each month and its conditions manually everytime?

Image of expected output is attached
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSbkZ.png)

Comment: Full Code is missing a select and who knows what else..

Answer (score -1):

Put code in procedure and pass useful parameters..

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you aware of procedures ? If not https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Not enough I realise, will take a look at it thanks for the info!